# Method to ravel an object numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have an object numpy ndarray like this:

```
array([array([1, 2]), array([2]), array([3]), array([4, 2, 3]),
       array([5, 4]), array([6, 3])], dtype=object)
```

Is there any method like `np.ravel()` to flatten this array? e.g:

```
[1,2,2,3,4,2,3,5,4,6,3]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`np.concatenate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) to convert to a "flattened" numpy array like so -

```
In [355]: obj1 = np.array([np.array([1, 2]), np.array([2]), np.array([3]), np.array([4, 2, 3]),
     ...:    np.array([5, 4]), np.array([6, 3])], dtype=object)

In [356]: np.concatenate(obj1)
Out[356]: array([1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 3])
```

Then, you can convert to a list with [`.tolist()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) -

```
In [357]: np.concatenate(obj1).tolist()
Out[357]: [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`numpy.concatenate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) which, as the name implies, concatenates a list/array of arrays into a flattened `numpy`-array:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import array

# some test data
a = array([array([1, 2]), array([2]), array([3]), array([4, 2, 3]),
    array([5, 4]), array([6, 3])], dtype=object)

np.concatenate(a)
# array([1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 3])
```